# Flutter bezier curves automatically deciding the control point

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to draw a bezier curve between the given two locations (offsets) with the flutter. I can see the following function available to do so,

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/quadraticBezierTo.html

Here we have to specify start and end points those I already know. And also have to specify the control point (x1,y1). I there a way we can generate this control point? May be to have more control of the curve we can have a factor (that decides how far away this point from the baseline) and based on that factor we can generate the control point.

Please find my scretch below 
[image]

Comment: so you need [perpendicular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpendicular) line to your baseline's center

Answer (score 2):

You can use cubicTo function

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/cubicTo.html

```
void cubicTo (
  double x1,
  double y1,
  double x2,
  double y2,
  double x3,
  double y3
)
```

this creates a bezier curve from the baseline (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) with (x3,y3) as control point.

```
class HalfCirclePainter extends CustomPainter {
  HalfCirclePainter({this.scrollOffset});

  final double scrollOffset;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint circle = new Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    Path topCirclePath = new Path()
      ..moveTo(0, 0)
      ..lineTo(0, scrollOffset < size.height ? scrollOffset : size.height)
      ..cubicTo(
        20,
        size.height,
        size.width - 20,
        size.height,
        size.width,
        scrollOffset < size.height ? scrollOffset : size.height,
      )
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0)
      ..lineTo(0, 0)
      ..close();

    canvas.drawPath(topCirclePath, circle);
  }
}
```

This code draws a semi circle, I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Yea with this function we can have a bezier curve. But here also we have to give values for the control point. What I am interested in an algorithm that automatically create the control point. So user only gives the start and end points. And program will calclulate the control point and draw the curve.

Comment: How would it know how curvy to make it?  You need three points to define a curve.

Comment: @randal how much curvy?? Yea we can decide it based on the factor I mentioned. What I simply want is on mobile app user will mark start and end points and we need to join them as a curve. We will not ask user to give the control point.

Comment: @lsc i already commented that you need your control point to be placed on the perpendicular line to your baseline's center - that way your curve will be symmetrical - what problem do you have with finding that perpendicular line?

Comment: @pskink yea exactly symmetrical curve will be fine for me. Yea the problem is finding that perpendicular line, is there any easy way of finding it with flutter?

Comment: @lsc see https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-parallel-perpendicular.html or https://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Equation-of-a-Perpendicular-Line-Given-an-Equation-and-Point - in flutter it should not take more than 3-4 lines of code - check [Offset](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Offset-class.html) official documentation

Comment: btw using `Offset` [operators](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Offset-class.html#operators) you can easily do it in just 2 lines of code - even with dynamic factor

Comment: @pskink 1) Find the equation of base line with the ‘point-slope equation’ with x1, y1 and x2, y2 values. Lets think that equation is y = mx + d. So we can find the value of m here. 
2) Then the perpendicular line equation would be q = (-1/m)*r + s and we know that (x1+x2)/2 , (y1+y2)/2 point will satisfy this equation we can find s here      ........... I don't think this is 2-3 lines of code. If you know a easy implementation please mention it here.

Comment: @lsc to find `m` you can for example use `end - start` where both `start` and `end` are your baseline offsets - read `Offset` complete documentation to make your life easier

Comment: @lsc and as i said its exactly 2 lines of code: `Offset baselineVector = end - start; Offset controlPoint = (start + end) / 2 + Offset(-baselineVector.dy, baselineVector.dx);` - your job is to make it parameterizable with `double fraction` which can range from `-∞` to `+∞`

Comment: @pskink Hello, thanks for your suggestion. It seems very easier than I thought.. :P

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for @pskink to help me. As you mentioned your answer as a comment and the code is not that readable when displaying in the comments. Here I am listing the code as the answer. So it is easy to grasp for someone who looking into this.

```
void drawBezierLine(Canvas canvas, Offset start, Offset end){
    Offset middle = end/2 + start/2;
    Offset baselineVector = end - start;
    Offset controlPoint = middle + Offset(-baselineVector.dy, baselineVector.dx);
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 8.0;

    var path = Path();
    path.moveTo(start.dx, start.dy);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(controlPoint.dx, controlPoint.dy, end.dx, end.dy);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

So here we can give start and end offsets to the function and it will draw the Bezier curve based on it. The hight of the Bezier(factor) curve corresponds to the length of the base line.